# Integral solution of two variable equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

Need to solve below question:

Find all solutions in integers $x$ and $y$ of the equation->>   $xy + 5x -8y = 79$

Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $$xy+5x-8y-40=39$$ or
$$(y+5)(x-8)=39,$$ and solve a number of systems:
$$x-8=-39$$ and $$y+5=-1...$$

For $$x-8\in\{-39,-13,-3,-1,1,3,13,39\}$$  you'll get all integer solutions.

Comment: I am not clear about the values (a,b) chosen for the rhs of the two equations (x - 8 = a; y + 5  = b). I feel the values should be such that a.b = 39. Then, these values can be derived from the set { 1, 13, 39, 3}. One value can be chosen, and the other derived based on the quotient = 39/ (earlier chosen value). Still, both will be from the same set.

Comment: @jiten Yes, of course! $x-8\in\{-39,-13,-3,-1,1,3,13,39\}$ and you'll get all integer solutions.

Comment: @jiten proceeding this way is available:  $$(y+5)(x-8)=39=d_1 \cdot d_2$$, $$\implies$$ $$\begin{cases}x=8+d_1 \\ y=-5+d_2\end{cases}$$ such that $$(d_1,d_2) \in \{(1,39),(39,1), (3,13),(13,3),(-1,-39), (-39,-1),(-3,-13),(-13,-3)\}$$So there should be 8 solutions total.  It's worth noting that this situation lacks symmetry, so switching $d_1$ and $d_2$ will give different solutions, besides that, I don't know if all this adds any worthwhile clarity or not but just a small suggestion.

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy Your  comment regarding symmetry adds a lot for looking the solution by an alternate view. I never knew that symmetry would be there in the solution sets obtained; i.e. had symmetry been there, 4 solutions would have been there. Can you please point a problem with such symmetry.

Comment: @jiten I wanted to express that the expressions arrived at will give different solutions for $x$ and $y $ if you were to switch the values of $d_1$ and $d_2$. Suppose instead we had that $$x=8 + d_1 + d_2$$. Then since we have the symmetric expression $ d_1 + d_2$, switching the values won't change the result

Comment: @jiten I made a similar argument in this question :  Ordered pairs of positive integers $2^{2x} - y^2 = 60$.  Wish I could link to it on my phone

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy I am unable to grasp the significance of the ordered pairs of positive integers given by : $ 2^{2x} - y^2 = 60 $. Hope more details, or link(s) will aid to understanding it.

Comment: @jiten see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262026/show-that-there-are-exactly-16-pairs-of-integers-x-y-such-that-11x8y17-xy/2418215#2418215 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416692/ordered-pairs-of-positive-integers-22x-y2-60/2416789#2416789

Comment: @jiten also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258204/finding-a-pythagorean-triple-a2-b2-c2-with-abc-40/2404098#2404098 as an example when there IS symmetry